# nginx set variable value to command output

Tags: nginx

I need to set a variable value to commmand output result on nginx is it possible? Something like this

```
location /uploads { 
 set $test $(ls -la /home/admin | wc -l)
```

}

This is a command example so this command if a execute on CLI it return the number 5 so the var on nginx should have the value 5 but it doesn´t work on nginx using $ output.

Is there any posibility to get it on nginx?

Comment: This is not possible with normal nginx. You can look into OpenResty, which is an enhanced nginx with built-in Lua module. It allows more elaborate scripting. Can you better describe the actual use case?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Thanks so much, I am trying to get the width and height of a image and save this value on a Var, I thought to use a CLI command that return the widht and save in a Var using $ output. Do you know if is possible to get the width and height of a image using nginx for example with Image resizer module? I saw the image_filter size option that return a json with this parameter but I don´t know how I could save it on a Var inside the location /uploads like in the example

Comment: JSON doesn't have any built-in JSON processing, so you still need Lua or nginx JS module for this. It is still not clear what the overall feature is that you are trying to implement. You are describing what method you are trying to use, but not the ultimate goal.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Thanks, the final goal is apply different options using image resizer library with a if statment so for this reason I need to get the height and width for example if $heigh is grather than $width the image is vertical so I use the option image_resizer crop 200 -; and if $width is grather than $heigh I use image_resizer - 200; In conclution is apply different values of the library depend of the original height and width of the original image so i need to get it this value for using in the if section

Comment: You should do this in the backend application side, with a PHP / Python / Ruby on rails etc. script. nginx is not the place to do such complex logic.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Thanks so much for the help I will search some library on php that can me help.